# Calculating the difference of elements in a vector with varying lag/lead

Tags: r, difference

I have some lab data and I am looking to calculate the difference between sample measurements over a moving time frame/window e.g 2 minutes (as apposed to 0-2, 2-4, 4-6 minute, static windows)
The problem is that although the data is sampled every second there are some missed samples (e.g. 1,2,4,6,7) so I cannot use a fixed lag function especially for larger time windows.

Here is the most promising I have tried. I have tried to calculate the difference in the row positions that will then use that to determine the lag value.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(sample_group = c(rep("a", 25), rep("b", 25)),t_seconds = c(1:50), measurement = seq(1,100,2))
df <- df[-c(5,10,23,33,44),] #remove samples

t_window = 5 

df_diff <- df %>%
  group_by(sample_group) %>%
  arrange(t_seconds) %>%
      mutate(lag_row = min(which(t_seconds >= t_seconds + t_window))- min(which(t_seconds == t_seconds)), #attempt to identify the lag value for each element 
             Meas_diff = measurement - lag(measurement, lag_row))
```

In this example (lag_row) I am trying to call an element from a vector and the vector itself, which obviously does not work! to make it clearer, I have added '_v' to identify what I wanted as a vector and '_e' as an element of that vector `min(which(t_seconds_v >= t_seconds_e + t_window))- min(which(t_seconds_v == t_seconds_e))`

I have tried to stay away from using loops but I have failed to solve the problem. 
I would appreciate if anyone has any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step should be inserting missing observations into your time series. Then you could fill the missing values using a Last-Observation-Carried-Backwards operation. This provides you with a complete regular time series.

Your desired output is very unclear, so the next step after that in the following example is just a guess. Adjust as needed.

```
#complete time series (using a data.table join):
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df_fill <- df[, .SD[data.table(t_seconds = min(t_seconds):max(t_seconds)), 
                    on = "t_seconds"], 
              by = sample_group]
df_fill[, filled := is.na(measurement)]

#last observation carried backwards
library(zoo)
df_fill[, measurement := na.locf(measurement, fromLast = TRUE), by = sample_group]

#differences
df_fill[, diff_value := shift(measurement, -t_window) - measurement, by = sample_group]
```

Comment: Thank you, this does what it needs to do. I did not think to add the missing values. I've never used the data.table package so this took me a while to understand and fit into my code (not the example). I am looking at the rate of change so I changed the last obs carried backwards to be a linear interpolation `df_fill[, measurement := na.approx(measurement, method = "linear"), by = c("sample_group")]`